# Extract 1 month older data using Shell scripts

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I need to find the entries from a huge log file which are 1 month older than the current date using shell scripts. The log entry date is in the 3rd field of each line. 
This is my sample log file:

```
0114374510,OK,10/23/2017 9:22:50 AM,0016692200,OK
0112364510,OK,10/23/2017 9:22:50 AM,0016692200,OK
0112364510,TX,10/21/2017 9:10:00 AM,0016692200,OK
0115364510,TX,10/21/2017 10:52:00 AM,0016692200,OK
0112368979,OK,7/29/2016 10:25:00 AM,0000718374,OK
0113368979,OK,7/29/2016 12:50:00 PM,0000718374,OK
0112368979,TX,9/16/2015 10:57:00 AM,0033545820,OK
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using `grep` to match certain lines in your file and `date` to manipulate dates.

#### Linux version

```
grep -E "$(date --date='-1 month' '+%m')/[0-9]+/$(date --date='-1 month' +'%Y') <your_file>"
```

- `date --date='-1 month' '+%m'` - Subtract 1 month to the current date and print the **month**
- `[0-9]+` - Regex matching any number (any day in our case)
- `$(date --date='-1 month' +'%Y')` - Subtract 1 month to the current date and print the **year**

#### macOS version

```
grep -E "$(date -v -1m '+%m')/[0-9]+/$(date -v -1m +'%Y') <your_file>"
```

- `date -v -1m '+%m'` - Subtract 1 month to the current date and print the **month**
- `[0-9]+` - Regex matching any number (any day in our case)
- `date -v -1m +'%Y'` - Subtract 1 month to the current date and print the **year**